# SonarQube 6.1 stopping itself. Not starting

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have installed Sonar qube 6.1. I have started sonar by executing `sonar.sh start` and checked status with `sonar.sh status`. After few seconds, sonar stopping itself by writing below statements in the `wrapper.log` file. Please help me on this issue to get resolve.

```
2017.05.04 07:01:13 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube-6.1/temp
2017.05.04 07:01:13 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube-6.1/temp -javaagent:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /opt/sonarqube-6.1/temp/sq-process4451619261882420874properties
2017.05.04 07:01:23 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
2017.05.04 07:01:23 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube-6.1/temp -javaagent:/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonarqube-6.1/lib/jdbc/h2/h2-1.3.176.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonarqube-6.1/temp/sq-process3625744255132410453properties
2017.05.04 07:01:25 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopping
2017.05.04 07:01:26 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopped
```

Comment: You should have other log files (web.log, es.log). Can you share them ?

Comment: Could you please tell me where can i find web.log, es.log files in UNIX environment ?

Comment: You'll find them in ${SONARQUBE_HOME}/logs/

Comment: The logs under logs folder are not rolling.

Comment: What do you mean by not rolling ?

Comment: Means.. logs are not getting updated which is under logs folder. I am not sure why...

Answer (score 1):

`es` is ElasticSearch, a component that indexes your data to accelerate searching. Maybe your indexes are corrupted. You can rebuild them by removing contents of `${SONARQUBE_HOME}/data/es/` directory, and retry.